# Is there something equivalent to TemplateBinding outside of a ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

I'm new to the styling part of WPF. What I want to do is to get the value of an attached property in a setter, e.g.:

```xml
<Trigger Property="SomeProperty" Value="SomeValue">
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty"
            Value="(My attached property, let's say lcl:MyClass.MyString)"/>
</Trigger>
```

I know that you can get something to this effect using a `{TemplateBinding lcl:MyClass.MyString}` in a `ControlTemplate`. My question is: can you do this in a style, without using a `ControlTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
<Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="{Binding Path=(lcl:MyClass.MyString), RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"/>
```

if your attached property applies to the element as your style. If not, you can use RelativeSource  or ElementName to find the appropriate element.

I am not sure how you have done that since your code lacks of details. Below code works:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" 
                Value="{Binding Path=(TestWebBrowser:AttachP.ValueEditorState), RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="label" TestWebBrowser:AttachP.ValueEditorState="HelloWorld"  Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="Disable Label" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Button's click event handler will set Label's IsEnabled to false to trigger the trigger. And note that you have to use Path= with parenthesis in the binding.

Comment: First of all, it's `RelativeSource` not `RelatedSource`. Secondly, this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it should be RelativeSource, my mistake. You need to know the object which applies the attached property. No matter in a style or a control template, what you need to do is to navigate to that object.